# Argument of type 'something' is not assignable to parameter of type 'something'

Tags: typescript, generics, enums

```
export enum MyNumber {
    ONE='ONE',
    TWO='TWO',
    THREE='THREE',
    FOUR='FOUR',
    FIVE='FIVE',
}

const sortByEnumOrdinal = <T>(enumType: T, enumList: T[]): T[] => {
    const orderedEnumValues = Object.values(enumType);
    const sortedEnumList = enumList.sort((a, b) => orderedEnumValues.indexOf(a) - orderedEnumValues.indexOf(b));

    return sortedEnumList;
}

const list = [MyNumber.THREE, MyNumber.FOUR, MyNumber.ONE];
sortByEnumOrdinal(MyNumber, list);

console.log(list);
```

The above is a enum and a generic function to sort any kind of enum list by ordinal. The function works fine, but the typescript is complaining on this line `sortByEnumOrdinal(MyNumber, list);`, with the error:

**Argument of type 'MyNumber[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(typeof MyNumber)[]'**

What did I do wrong and how to fix this typescript error?

Comment: `MyNumber` used as a value has a type `typeof MyNumber`. You give that to your function so it expects an array of `typeof MyNumber`. You can get the desired enum type `MyNumber` with `typeof MyNumber[keyof MyNumber]`, so in your code it would be `enumList: (T[keyof T])[]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix in your current code

change this

```
const list = [MyNumber.THREE, MyNumber.FOUR, MyNumber.ONE];
```

to this

```
const list = [{ONE : 'ONE',FOUR : 'FOUR', THREE : 'THREE'}]
```

It will fix this Error

[image]

Comment: It will fix the error but not have the desired behavior.